# How to write code to compare Japanese strings in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, internationalization

We have an Excel file with the 'Company' document property set in Japanese, and we have code that reads the 'Company' document property and stores it as a string.

However, we do not know how to compare it against a reference/benchmark Japanese string to see if it matches.

Two questions, please:

1) What code is needed to do this comparison?

Right now, I'm using the String Comparer solution here: 
[Compare strings with non-English characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578304/compare-strings-with-non-english-characters)

```
var swedishComparer = StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("sv-Se"), true);
consultants = consultants.Where(x => x.Description.Contains(vm.Description, swedishComparer)).ToList();
```

2) How would I store the reference/benchmark Japanese string?

That is, what should I use for 'ReferenceStringInJapanese' here:

```
japaneseComparer.Compare(companyName, 'ReferenceStringInJapanese') == 0
```

Comment: For #1, you should post your actual code. I don't see an accepted solution in your link.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but you should use the Japanese text you are trying to compare.  You can load it from a etc or you can paste it in (assuming visual studio).

Comment: @BioBuckyBall: I wasn't aware I could just paste it in. I thought I'd have to save it as a resource or some such. Will try that. Thanks.

Comment: @BioBuckyBall: That seems to have worked. Thank you. If you post your answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Visual Studio editor supports Unicode, so you should be able to paste strings of Japanese text directly into the editor.

Answer (score 3):

To compare the two strings, you can use a StringComparer, as you already discovered. Use it with a *ja-JP* CultureInfo for Japanese input:

```
var comparer = StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("ja-JP"), true);
```

The string to compare against can simply be placed in your source code. C# supports Unicode.

```
bool areEqual = comparer.Equals(input, "こんにちは");
```