# Unable to mach strings in sqlite-net query in Greek language

Tags: xamarin.forms, c#-7.0, sqlite-net

I want to return from sqlite database some strings based on what the user typed. The comparison must be case-insensitive. While my query works for English data, it only works for Greek when all letters are Caps. So I guess that the method ToUpper() performs differently in the query and in the code.

I've narrowed down the problem to the ToUpper() method because when I run it outside of the query to the filter string it performs great for capital letters.

```
var filterString = filter.Designation?.ToUpper();
            var sites = from c in MemoryService.DbContext.db.Table<Site>()
                         where filterString == null || c.Designation.ToUpper().Contains(filterString)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a culture specific comparison, see this post here. 
[Compare strings with non-English characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578304/compare-strings-with-non-english-characters)

This assumes you know what language the compared strings will be typed in.

Comment: what you suggest is not possible because the upper line gets transformed to SQL behind the scenes and unfortunately the sqlite-net-pcl plugin for Xamarin Forms doesn't recognize this kind of comparison